# Set up a specific key for RSA OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

I'm currentlyt trying to implement some test vectors for RSA implementations, and I wanted to test them over OpenSSL v1.1.0f implementation. However, when I try to set up the key (for e, n p, q or d), I have the following error :

> erreur : dereferencing pointer to incomplete type « RSA {alias struct rsa_st} »

My code is the following :

```
int rsa_encrypt(byte *in, size_t in_len, byte *out, const char *n, const char *e, char padding){
    int err = -1;

    RSA *keys = NULL;
    keys = RSA_new();

    BN_hex2bn(&keys->n, n); // error here
    BN_hex2bn(&keys->e, e); // and here

    out = malloc(RSA_size(keys));

    if (padding == OAEP ) {
        err = RSA_public_encrypt(in_len, in, out, keys, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
    }
    else if (padding == v1_5) {
        err = RSA_public_encrypt(in_len, in, out, keys, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    }

    RSA_free(keys);

    return err;
}
```

Where n and e are a string representing my parameter in hexa.

I've looked for the structure corresponding to the RSA type, and found [this](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/rsa.html). 
I don't understand why I can't set up n and e... Any idea ?

Comment: From the documentation you linked: *"applications should generally avoid using RSA structure elements directly and instead use API functions to query or modify keys"*. The implementation you use may be keeping the `struct` contents hidden because they use different fields.

Comment: I saw that, but I thought it was mainly for security reasons, which aren't part of my concern for test vectors. Do you have any idea of which API they're referring to ?

Comment: Have you included openssl/rsa.h ?

Comment: @Pras Yes, openssl/rsa.h and openssl/bn.h

Comment: Are you using 1.0.2 or lower, or 1.1.0 which is current (although 1.1.1 is in beta and may be released soon)? 1.1.0 changed _many_ API structures that were formerly exposed and made them opaque, including RSA = struct rsa_st. Also note OpenSSL uses CRT-form RSA private key which requires not just n,e,d,p,q but also dmod(p-1), dmod(q-1), and qinvmodp. Is there some reason you don't just create, store, and then use DER (or even PEM) key blobs like everybody else?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I'm using OpenSSL 1.1.0f (I will add it in my post).

I don't use the create, store then use DER/PEM because I would like to be able to test a lot of things, including the behavior of an implementation when we give it a wrong key, so I need to control every aspect of the key. Moreover, I'm working with an interface which give me each key element individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenSSL structs are opaque in 1.1.x, you can't talk about their fields.  Among other things, it allows for new struct fields to be added during servicing releases, since caller code can't know the field offset.

For 1.1.x you'd need to do something akin to

```
BN* bnN = NULL;
BN* bnE = NULL;
RSA* keys = RSA_new();

BN_hex2bn(&bnN, n);
BN_hex2bn(&bnE, e);
RSA_set0_key(keys, bnN, bnE, NULL);

...
RSA_free(keys);
// do not free bnN or bnE, they were freed by RSA_free.
```

Note that I left out the requisite error checking.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for ! I edited your message for some minor corrections (eg type name).